# Why I am getting IamRoleLambdaExecution error when creating a lambda function with dynamodb and s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

I am using dynamodb and s3 object, in my lambda function. I am getting IamRoleLambdaExecution, error when I try to deploy the lambda function.

The full error says

```
Actions/Conditions must be prefaced by a vendor, e.g., iam, sdb, ec2, etc. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: e1083796-7b8d-45d2-a9ac-8a9f01f78a6a; Proxy: null)
```

Here is my serverless.yaml

```
service: serverless-gpt-app

frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: prod
  region: eu-central-1
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  memorySize: 256

  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:DescribeTable
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
            - s3*
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:s3:::user-text-bucket/*
            - arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:183747912409:table/user-text


functions:
  hello:
    handler: app.server
    events: # events trigger lambda functions
      - http: # this is an API Gateway HTTP event trigger
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
      - http: # all routes get proxied to the Express router
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
```

Comment: try `s3:*` instead of `s3*`. Also, Normally, you would split dynamodb and s3 into 2 different statements inside of `statements` array.

Comment: Man it worked. Thanks. ❤ from India.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below with `s3:*` and with separate statements for different resources:

```
iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:DescribeTable
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:183747912409:table/user-text
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - s3:*
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:s3:::user-text-bucket/*
```

Formatting may need adjusting as it's written from my phone.